# node executable not found error in jdeveloper when deploying maf app

Tags: java, android, deployment, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

node executable not found error in jdeveloper when i deploying android  maf application on device,i also install adb and i can see my device by adb device command in platform-tools directory of android sdk,i can't run sdk because lack of pc configuration

error after deploying-----

```
[12:05:48 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[12:05:48 PM] Target platform is  (Android).
[12:05:49 PM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "Employees" to Android using profile "Android3".
[12:05:49 PM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[12:05:52 PM] Started Android Debug Bridge server.
[12:05:52 PM] Verifying a single Android device is online and connected to the ADB server...
[12:05:52 PM] Unable to obtain the version of ARM supported by the Android device.  The application may not work correctly if the device does not support at least ARMv6.
[12:05:52 PM] Cordova Plugman could not be found and needs to be installed.
[12:05:52 PM] This one-time installation may take a few minutes.
[12:05:52 PM] Installing Cordova Plugman...
[12:05:58 PM] Command-line executed: [/home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java, -jar, /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/maf-helper.jar, installTools, -tools, /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools]
[12:05:58 PM] Creating directory /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/plugman
[12:05:58 PM] Installing plugman ...
[12:05:58 PM] Error Code : INTERNAL_ERROR
[12:05:58 PM] /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/npm: 2: exec: /home/yogesh/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/node: not found
[12:05:58 PM] oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[12:05:58 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.installTools(Unknown Source)
[12:05:58 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.MafHelperMain.main(Unknown Source)
[12:05:58 PM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[12:05:58 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.runProcess(Unknown Source)
[12:05:58 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.executeCmd(Unknown Source)
[12:05:58 PM] ... 2 more
[12:05:58 PM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[12:05:58 PM] ... 4 more
[12:05:58 PM] Caused by: java.lang.Exception
[12:05:58 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException.<init>(Unknown Source)
[12:05:58 PM] ... 4 more
[12:05:58 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[12:05:59 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[12:05:59 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[12:05:59 PM] An error occurred installing plugman. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.common.deployers.plugins.PlugmanInstallerDeployer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the culprit is compatibility issue of the *node executable(.../Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/node)* that comes alongside jdeveloper with the OS. The official release of jdeveloper consists of a 32 bit(x86) release of node. So if you experienced this problem you may be using a 64 bit OS.

To run a 32-bit executable file on a 64-bit multi-architecture Ubuntu system, you have to add the i386 architecture and install the three library packages libc6:i386, libncurses5:i386, and libstdc++6:i386:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or below, use this:

```
 echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Then enter:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```